# Не удаляется элемент из базы данных

Tags: java, spring-jpa, repository, one-to-many

метод deleteSubject. Через Post запрос я получаю id элемента, ищу ещё через репозиторий и он его находит, по логам в if попадет. Пытался удалить этот элемент через delete / deleteById репозитория этого элемента, но он не удалятся.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: Что значит _не удаляется_?  Удалённый элемент остаётся в базе?  Или в коллекции `subjectList` в классе `User`?

Comment: элемент остаётся в базе данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте установить `orphanRemoval = true` для коллекции и добавьте метод(ы) для добавления элементов в коллекцию, которые устанавливали/разрывали бы связь между сущностями:

```java
public class User implements UserDetails {
    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subjectList.add(subject);
        subject.setUser(this);
    }

    public void removeSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subjectList.remove(subject);
        subject.setUser(null);
    }
}
```

Исправленный сервисный метод -- в репозитории надо будет вызвать метод `save`/`saveAndFlush`:

```java
public void deleteSubject(User user, Long subjectId) {
    subjectRepository.findById(subjectId)
        .ifPresentOrElse(subject -> {
            user.removeSubject(subject);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }, () -> log.warn("Subject not found by id {}", subjectId));
}
```